Installing OpenDMARC on CentOS 9
When I try to install OpenDMARC on CentOS 9 I get an error regarding perl(Switch):
dnf install opendmarc
Last metadata expiration check: 0:41:05 ago on Fri 06 Dec 2024 04:23:37 PM GMT.
Error:
Problem: conflicting requests
nothing provides perl(Switch) needed by opendmarc-1.4.2-22.el9.x86_64 from epel
(try to add '-skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '-nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

dnf whatprovides "perl(Switch)"
Last metadata expiration check: 2:52:54 ago on Thu 12 Dec 2024 03:27:15 PM GMT.
Error: No matches found. If searching for a file, try specifying the full path or using a wildcard prefix ("*/") at the beginning.


To answer my own question, perl(Switch) is hiding in the crb repo. Enabling the crb repo before installing OpenDMARC solves the issue.
dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb

